# How to prove the non existence of this integral?

Tags: improper-integrals

How to prove that
\begin{equation}\nonumber
\int_0^\infty \sin^2\left[\pi\left(x + \frac{1}{x}\right)\right]dx
\end{equation}
does not exist?

Comment: For large $x$ we have $x+1/x\approx x$. Thus we have something like $\int_M^\infty \sin^2 u\,du$ at the upper end. This contributes $\pi$ for each period of $u$ of length $2\pi$, and those contributions add up. I would try $u=x+1/x$, when you can bound $du/dx$ away from zero for large enough $x$.

Comment: Do you mean "not exist" or "not converge"?

Comment: @Draks: Yes, I meant "does not converge".

Answer (score 1):

Write it as $\int_0^\infty \frac12 (1- \cos(\pi(2x+2/x)))dx$. Even the constant factor $\frac12$ results in an infinite integral...

Comment: Thanks. However, do we need to show that $\smallint_0^\infty \cos(\pi(2x + 2/x))dx$ is convergent? It should not happen that we write the integral as a sum of two terms each of which is separately divergent but the sum ends up being convergent.

Comment: To my knowlegde even $\int_0^\infty \cos(x)$ doesn't have an explicite value, so I don't expect one for your integral. Jyrki's approach seems to be a good one...